# How to put page from PDF on page before ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf, titles, pdfpages, backgrounds

So I am making "this" file in which I do not have title page i.e. none page before table of contest one, because I've made title page in other program and converted it to PDF form and know I am trying to place it in front of ToC, but to be there without background I've placed and without page numbering, here is what I've tried(Pocetna is that PDF file and Pozadina is background):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=.99,  %% adjust
contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.982\paperheight]{Pozadina}}
}
%% ...
\setcounter{page}{0}
\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=1\textheight]{Pocetna}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
%%...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see if the following would have been helpful. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Integrating_the_title_page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `pdfpages` is already loaded. It can be used to load the title page from the `Pozadina.pdf`:

```
\begin{document}
  \includepdf{Pozadina}
  \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf{example-image-a}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to center that page nicely, but then instead of page from PDF it puts background over whole page.
So what I did now, that works is putted \backgroundsetup{contents={}}
just before the command  
\includepdf{Pozadina}